# Azure DevOps PAT for package repo works for local Maven builds but not in DevOps build pipeline

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Are there any special steps to use a personal access token (PAT) to connect to a Maven package repository hosted in another Azure DevOps organization than the AzDO project where a build is happening?

I am recreating a project from one Azure DevOps organization into another. Cloning the repo was easy enough, and I was able to duplicate the AzDO Build Pipeline's steps via export and import into the new org.

The project build pipeline requires a Maven package repository from the source organization which will stay hosted there. Within that imported pipeline, I created a personal access token (PAT) on the source org and set it up as a service connection for the target build pipeline with a Maven Authenticate step(s) to get the credentials into the build's settings.xml file.

Unfortunately, all builds still fail from what appears to be 401 warnings where it seems to fail to retrieve all the package dependencies. Here's an example warning from the failed build log (where `{source package repo URL}` being the URL of the source organization's package repo).

> [WARNING] org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xmlfailed to transfer from {source package repo URL} during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central ({source package repo URL}): authentication failed for {source package repo URL}/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml, status: 401 Unauthorized

After all the package warnings, the build fails. Again, the message seems to imply failed retrieval of dependencies.

> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

The same Maven build with a PAT setup on my local dev machine user account *does* successfully build with the token added to my user settings.xml file.

If it helps, the Maven Authenticate steps logs this pair of warnings as well (where `{repo1}` and `{repo2}` are the names of two repositories hosted in that source organization).

> ##[warning]The settings for the feed or repository '{repo1}' already exists in the users settings.xml file.
> ##[warning]The settings for the feed or repository '{repo2}' already exists in the users settings.xml file.

I've also since tried making one Maven Authenticate step per package repo, which results in only a single warning in the second auth step.